# Unable to find explicit activity (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

i made a new activity and when i im trying to move between them by clicking a button the app crash and logcat shows the error below

```
    12-16 14:02:09.016 23235-23235/com.modather.scalculate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.modather.scalculate, PID: 23235
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.modather.scalculate/android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java)
at com.modather.scalculate.HomePage$onCreate$1.onClick(HomePage.kt:36)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:107)
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".HomePage"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.modather.scalculate.age"
        android:label="Calculate my age(SC)" />
</application>
```

i had searched over stackoverflow and found some solution but it didn't work for me.. so if it possible to fix mine ?
Here's the moving code

```
fab.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, activity_age::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Typing mistake check it

your activity name is **`activity_age`** and you have added in manifest **`age`** is

```
fab.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this,age::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: @MethoYehia what is the name of your activity

Comment: the activity name is "age"

Comment: @MethoYehia than use this **`val intent = Intent(this, age::class.java)`**

Comment: @MethoYehia happy to help you my friend